# I'm trying to set quorum-dev-quickstart Hyperledger Besu and I cant access the endpoints of following services?

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-besu

private network
npx quorum-dev-quickstart
I'm trying to set quorum-dev-quickstart Hyperledger Besu and I cant access the endpoints of following services ?List endpoints and services
JSON-RPC HTTP service endpoint : http://localhost:8545
JSON-RPC WebSocket service endpoint : ws://localhost:8546
Web block explorer address : http://localhost:25000/

this is what i followed :
npx quorum-dev-quickstart

Which Ethereum client would you like to run? Default: (1) My answer: 1

Hyperledger Besu
GoQuorum
Do you want to try out Codefi Orchestrate? Note: choosing yes will direct you to a login/registration page. [Y/n] My answer: n

Do you wish to enable support for private transactions? [Y/n] My answer: y

Do you wish to enable support for logging with Splunk or ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash & Kibana)? Default: (1) My answer: 3

None
Splunk
ELK
Where should we create the config files for this network? Please
choose either an empty directory, or a path to a new directory that does not yet exist. Default: ./quorum-test-network
./quorum-test-network

✅ Installation complete.
To start your test network, run 'run.sh' in the directory, './quorum-test-network'

cd quorum-test-network

./run.sh

Quorum Dev Quickstart

Start network
Quorum Dev Quickstart

List endpoints and services
JSON-RPC HTTP service endpoint : http://localhost:8545
JSON-RPC WebSocket service endpoint : ws://localhost:8546
Web block explorer address : http://localhost:25000/